# How can I get a FileStorage object from string

Tags: python

I have this string:

```
str = "FieldStorage('myfile', 'file.exe', 'hello\\n')"
```

So I would like to know if there is a way to get the FileStogare object from that string

Comment: Why do you have that? Where is the string coming from?

Comment: I get the string from a `unicode(request.post_vars["myfile"])` the reason is because a FileStorage is not serializable in JSON and I need to pass the file through json @DanielRoseman

Comment: Why don't you serialize the parameters needed to reconstruct the object instead? Why do you need to serialize the whole object?

Comment: @EdwardSuárez but this makes no sense. That string is just a description of a file container; it doesn't contain any of the file's actual data. So what's the point?

Comment: @VincentSavard thnaks for the comment.
I was just curious XD, I solved my problem by saving the file and passing the path as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could. The question is, should you?

```
str = "FieldStorage('myfile', 'file.exe', 'hello\\n')"
obj = eval(str)
```

Comment: In this case, it's a _terrible_ idea because the string comes from a user.

Comment: @VincentSavard I definitely agree.